# Dictionary of misspelled words

Tags: data-request, dictionary

I am looking for a dictionary of common misspelled words that can be used to highlight errors. I am not looking for a normal dictionary as I don’t want to hit things like names.

It cannot include words like 'affect', which although is a common misspelling, is also a valid word.

Something like the auto-correct dictionary used in Microsoft Word would be a good start, but broader because it is not required make an accurate match to a single expected word.

Comment: Why not use something along the lines of [Aspell](http://aspell.net/)?

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a [Wikipedia page about this very topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aLists_of_common_misspellings), and they maintain [a machine-readable list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aLists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines) that you can use as a starting point if you're writing a tool.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you: [Word List - Commonly Misspelled English Words](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/word-list-commonly-misspelled-english-words)

Comment: There's a broken link here.